# Python functions are called too soon in Django

Tags: python, django

Even if I assign it to a variable, the API call triggers too soon.

I've implemented a few ideas, as shown in the examples (not the actual code, but same principles).

```
""" Example #1 """

fruit = 'banana'

def search_engine(fruit):
    engine = {
        'apple': google.search(Time="10 hours ago"),
        'banana': yahoo.searchNow(Time="12 min ago"),
        'pear': bing.searchNow(Time="13h ago"),
        }
    print(engine[fruit])

search_engine(fruit)



""" Example #2 """

fruit = 'banana'

def search_engine(fruit):
    GS = google.search(Time="10 hours ago")
    YS = yahoo.searchNow(Time="12 min ago")
    BS = bing.searchNow(Time="13h ago")

    engine = {
        'apple': GS,
        'banana': YS,
        'pear': BS,
        }
    print(engine[fruit])
```

Let's assume that Time is an improper value, and will throw an exception regardless.

in Example #1, however, "apple" is called first and throws an exception, when "banana" should be called instead.

In Example #2, it throws an exception at "GS = google.search(Time....", instead of doing it for "YS = yahoo.searchNow..."

I've only had this issue since trying to integrate my Python project into Django.

Comment: Why would banana be called (you are not 'calling' banana by the way, but that's a different issue) first?

Comment: Please elaborate on why banana isn't being "called".

Comment: Because you don't have a callable (e.g. a function) named `banana`. That's irrelevant though. Can you explain why do you expect that `yahoo.search()` should be called first?

Comment: Let me restate, "call" isn't the proper term. 

Why isn't "yahoo.searchNow(Time="12 min ago")" being printed?

Comment: Because you get an exception in the previous (`google...`) line.

Comment: Ok, I get that. Can you explain how I would be able to get (yahoo...) to give me an exception instead?

Comment: You can use an `if`/`elif` clause to determine which function to run, or use function objects as dictionary values instead of calling them.

Comment: Honestly, It would be 190% better if you just posted the real code or a good approximation

Comment: Is there a more practical way to do this besides making function objects? In reality, I'd add more "fruits" with different API calls/function objects, and I'd like to do it as dynamically as possible. 

And this is actually a very very close approximation to my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should store the callables and their args separately, and call them when you retrieve the item.

```
engine = {
    'apple': (google.search, {"Time": "10 hours ago"}),
    'banana': (yahoo.searchNow, {"Time": "12 min ago"}),
    'pear':  (bing.searchNow, {"Time": "13h ago"}),
    }
obj, kwargs = engine[fruit]
print(obj(**kwargs))
```

Answer (score 0):

Exceptions are thrown while initializing engine dictionary, because you calling those function during initialization, use callable and kwargs instead.